# How do I get all items in a list that are inside of another list?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, list, c#-4.0, lambda

I know the title is not great but I think the code will come across a lot better.

Say I have the following class:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<Object> ObjectList = new List<Object>;
}
```

Now let's say I have a `list<Test> listOfTest` that has 100 items in its list, and each Test object in the list has 100 items in its `List<Object> ObjectList` list.

Can I use LINQ, Lambda expression or anything to quickly get all the Objects's from every Test object?

Currently I have to do the following:

```
var items = new List<Object>();
foreach(var testobj in listOfTest)
{
    items.AddRange(testObj.ObjectList);
}
```

I do know I could do listOfTest.foreach() but it really comes down to still needing the foreach.

I personally do NOT like this and think it is a hack almost and there must be a better way to do this. So the question is basically, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That is a single layer deep list, and not at all what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var items = listOfTest.SelectMany(lt => lt.myInnerObject).ToList();
```